# JS Intl.DateTimeFormat hours start at 7

Tags: javascript, datetime

When I run:

```js
const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  second: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour: "2-digit"
}).formatToParts(0);

console.log(date);
```

it says that that the hour is 7, but shouldn't it be 0? I was thinking it might be something with PST being offset 7 hours from UTC but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: That code doesn't say the hour is 7? It says the hour is 1.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you when I run it it says "07" for hour. Seems to me all the more reason to figure out how to standardize it.

Comment: What environment are you running it in? What is your time zone?

Comment: I am running it in Chrome 83 in EST, I also tested it in firefox & edge

Comment: I don’t know what to say. I’ve run it on three devices and all say 01 am. I’ve tried it in EST, AEST, GMT, and BST.

Comment: https://runkit.com/evolutionxbox/5f14eb95b8a621001adbe003 Please check I’m not going crazy

Comment: Yeah there it gives "01". How did you test it in different timezones? I tested it by changing the locale, but that didn't seem to affect it.

Comment: I changed my time zone on each device. It didn’t change anything though.

Comment: I found if you set the `timeZone` field you can standardize it but setting it to "UTC" gives me the hours as 24 instead of 0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time value of a Date is based on UTC, but the default stringified values for Date parts are based on local time. So your assumption about PST offset is correct.

You will get the expected result if you set the output timezone to UTC:

```js
const date = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  second: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour: "2-digit",
  hour12: false,
  timeZone: 'UTC'
}).formatToParts(0);

console.log(date);
```

Note that you must set *hour12* to `false`, otherwise it will return 12 am.

If you get hour 24 instead of 0, set [*hourCycle*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to "h23". The hour cycle should be set by the language ('en-US'), however it may not. Setting the *hourCycle* should override the default to ensure you get 0 for midnight not 24.